# Fated to earn money

Tags: mathematics, story

Here's a puzzle I made.
Joe has investments in Company A, Company B, and Company C.

Joe is fated to earn $25.00 from Company A within 2 days from now.

Joe is fated to earn $45.00 from Company B within 3 days from now.

Joe is fated to earn $100.00 from Company C within 5 days from now.

Joe is fated to earn no more than $26.00 from Company C and Company B on day 1 (1 day from now).

Joe is fated to earn at least $14.00 from Company A and Company C on day 2 (2 days from now).

Joe has to earn twice the amount of money on the first day than the second day from Companies A, B, and C and twice the amount of money on the second day than the third day from Companies A, B, and C. This can be expressed algebraically as Joe earning x money on day 3 (3 days from now), 2x money on day 2 (2 days from now), and 4x money on day 1 (1 day from now).

Joe can earn whatever amount of money (that satisfies the other conditions) from Companies A, B, and C on day 4 and day 5 (4 and 5 days from now).

What is the lowest amount of money Joe can earn on day 1 (1 day from now) from Companies A, B, and C? Explain your reasoning.

P.S. How come there doesn't seem to be good formulas to use for this question?

Hint:

> You won't have to calculate in cents for this question.

Comment: Is that 4x money on day 1?

Comment: Yes, it is, my bad. Edited. Copied my question wrong. Should be ok now.

Comment: When you say within earn X money within 2 days, is it valid for just first 2 days, or any pair of consecutive two days?

Comment: just first 2 days

Comment: This appears to be a straightforward mathematics question. I can't see the puzzley/fun part of it?

Comment: It uses logical reasoning to reach the answer. If you see my answer, no formulas are used. Very little calculation is required.

Comment: Should I ask it on mathematics stack exchange instead?

Comment: @YukangJiang No, MSE is not usually for questions where you already know the answer. If there is a trick here to avoid algebra, then it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Well, I honestly have no idea if it belongs here, but I worked hard to create the question and I want to share it somewhere. There is a bit of algebra, but it's really simple and there's logic on top of it.

Comment: I don't mind moving it to mathematics stack exchange btw.

Answer (score 2):

> So I started with hard limit, and tried to adjust the numbers, which was pretty straight forward, There may be other permutations possible, haven't really gotten into algebra portion of it. 
>  Since at least A and B earnings together are 70 dollars over first 3 days, then it means that best outcome is: 40/20/10. (4x + 2x + x = 70) 
>  At same time, Day 1 maximum income is 51 dollars (A: 25 dollars, B+C: 26 dollars). 
>  Since, it is mentioned answer is not in cents, then only solution space is 40, 44, and 48.
>  So brute force solution:
>  (Start by keeping in mind that C earning can be adjusted for Day 4 and day 5, so only add it when required)
> -- Fix the maximum earning for B on day 1, and adjust for A.
> -- This gives Earning for A on day 2. That gives the earning for C on day 2, which gives the earning for B
> -- Day 3 is pretty simple, adjust for B, and check if equation makes sense. If it does, answer achieved, else move on to next
>  Try for 40 Day 1: 14/26/0 Day 2: 11/6/3 Day 3: 0/10*/0 B required, 13, not possible
>  Try for 44: Day 1: 18/26/0 Day 2: 7/8/7 Day 3: 0/11/0 And voila :)

Comment: For Company A, you have 14 on day 1 and 9 on day 2. That's 23 dollars  total not 25 dollars, but you are right in C earnings only being necessary to add when required

Comment: Fixed, thankfully didn't changed the answer

Comment: You have total Company B earnings at 26 (Day 1) + 6 (Day 2) + 8 (Day 3). That's 40 dollars, not 45. Company B earnings should be 45 dollars over the three day or less period. I think the answer is a little higher than 40 dollars for day 1.

Comment: Ah my bad.. somehow, while solving $40 got stuck in my head for B, and I didn't double check :\

Comment: Good attempt though :D

Comment: Brute force solution. Hopefully, someone will have more elegant solution, and even more hopefully, my sleep deprived brain haven't made even more silly errors this time

Comment: Yes, your brute force solution is correct. Hopefully someone will be able to reason through it.